# multi band to single band for raster in R

Tags: r, raster

I have the following raster:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1446, 1243, 1797378  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent      : 4210000, 5453000, 3372000, 4818000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : -
names       : ALL_2016_year_Raster 
values      : 0, 36293  (min, max)
```

It seems like it is a multiband raster but I would like to export it as a single band raster. when I import it, i used `raster <-  raster(file, band=1)` but it does not change anything...

Is there a way to make it single band?

Comment: Is a single band raster. `class: RasterLayer` is enough to detect a single band raster. Other classes are `RasterStack` and `RasterBrick`, and for them, you can expect 4 dimensions: `(nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayer)`

Comment: your example here is a single band raster; how do you think its multiband?

Comment: I've exported single band rasters from R, and ArcMap thinks it's a multi-band raster for some reason. Is there an argument to specify single band when writing (even though it is single band)?